# How to define time unit and time precision

Tags: system-verilog

```
//`timescale 10ps/1fs
module time_presion();
    timeunit 100ps/10ps; //If We change this to 100ns/10ps it works fine
    parameter p=11.49;
    int a;
    initial begin
        $monitor("%t ,My values Changes %d",$time,a);
        #p a = 10;
        #p a = 30;
        #p a = 40;
        //#100us;
        #p a = 50;
        #1 $finish(1);
    end
endmodule
```

When I run this code, I get this error:

```
file: time_prcision.sv
    timeunit 100ps/10ps;
           |
ncvlog: *E,TUSERR (time_prcision.sv,4|11): timeunit is smaller than the specified time precision [IEEE Std 1800-2009].
    module worklib.time_presion:sv
        errors: 1, warnings: 0
```

If I change the timeunit to `100ns/10ps`, then the code runs properly.  What is wrong in the above code?

Comment: The code given by you is working fine as here time unit (100ps) is larger than time precision (10ns). Please check:  http://www.edaplayground.com/x/SLv

Comment: Yes it works in EdaPlayground but while run with NC version 10 and 14 it is showing this error i tried in both version.

Comment: Specify the time precision as separate statement and then check the result. This is just trial and error.. ;-)

Comment: Yes ,with defining time unit and timeprecision separate it works.

Answer (score 7):

From SystemVerilog [LRM 1800-2012](https://blogs.mentor.com/verificationhorizons/blog/2013/02/25/ieee-1800-2012-systemverilog-published/), section 3.14.2.2:

> The time unit and precision can be declared by the timeunit and timeprecision keywords, respectively, and set to a time literal (see 5.8).

The line `timeunit 100ps/10ps;` defines the **time unit** in **current** module,program, package or interface, locally.

> If specified, the timeunit and timeprecision declarations shall **precede** any other items in the **current time scope**.

The **time unit** tells that when you give `#1` delay (for example) the unit of that delay. If we select `100ps` as time unit, then providing `#1` delay shall result in **100ps** delay.

The **time precision** tells the **smallest** **delay** you can configure in a given time unit. Precision represent how many **decimal points** of precision to use **relative** to the time units. For example:

```
timescale 100ps/10ps shall have a #1 delay of 100ps 
while you can give #0.1 as the smallest delay i.e. of 10ps.

timescale 1ns/1ps shall have `#1` as 1ns and `#0.001` 
as 1ps as the smallest delay.
```

In your code, `timescale 10ps/1fs` shall represent a `#1` of **10ps** delay and `#0.0001` is the **smallest measurable delay**. Now, coming to the error:

```
timeunit is smaller than the specified time precision
```

Intuitively, it can be said that time unit must **never** be smaller than time precision. This is stated in the above error.

A timescale of `100ps/10ps` shall **round-off** every delay after one decimal place. Providing 11.49 shall be rounded off to **11.5** and multiplied by time precision and then displayed.

In short, using `timescale 1ns/1ps`, delays are interpreted to be in nanoseconds and any fractions to be rounded-off to the nearest picosecond. I used `$realtime` in display statement and the output is as follows. The display `115` is due to default time scaling `(time*timeunit/timeprecision)` in timeformat.

```
              0 ,My values Changes           0
             115 ,My values Changes          10
             230 ,My values Changes          30
             345 ,My values Changes          40
             460 ,My values Changes          50
```

For more information, refer to [timeunit](http://www.edaboard.com/thread240419.html), [difference between time unit and time precision](http://www.eda.org/sv-bc/hm/0323.html) and [time scale tutorial](http://www.testbench.in/TB_13_TIME_SCALE_AND_PRECISION.html) links.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your code. I think this is a problem with nc/irun/xrun; even the recent versions still give this error. On the other hand, vcs compiles it without any issues.

Update Sep 2021: Still broken in xrun!

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been reported to Cadence, and they plan to fix it in a future release of their simulator.

As mentioned in the Comments, the workaround solution to avoid the compile error is to use 2 separate statements:

```
timeunit     100ps;
timeprecision 10ps;
```

Note: The `ncvlog: *E,TUSERR` error is also seen with the version of the Cadence simulator currently available on edaplayground (Incisive 15.20).